# How to use tailwindCSS in .hbs file

Tags: node.js, express, tailwind-css, hbs

I am facing issues while using tailwindCss in hbs file . Can someone tell me the procedure of integrating the tailwindCss in .hbs file?

I have tried many things but the inline property of tailwindcss is not applying to any element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. I found it pretty straight forward.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<div class="h-full w-16 bg-gray-800 flex justify-center">
        
</div>
```

You can also checkout their [installation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) guide.